# Unable to get the text of webelement in selenium web driver for bootstrap-dropdown using xpath

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I want to access each bootstrap dropdown menus in SERVICES and then have to select one service and click on that
refer this website, https://mybmtc.karnataka.gov.in/english

I use this XPath

```
IList<IWebElement> menus = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='navbar - default']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
```

This is the inspect element code:
Services

--> --> -->Chartered Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hover on Service, use the below CSS :

```
a[title='Services']
```

then Select the link `Chartered Services` using `link_text`.

to hover :

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Actions hover = builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='Services']
"))).Build().Perform();
```

and then click :

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Chartered Services")).Click();
```

Comment: Adding to the above, you can create a generic method passing two arguments like menu and menu item to be selected, use those variables for dynamic locator values.

Comment: @Akshay : That makes sense

Comment: Thanks you @cruisepandey, the above code is working